# Excel Filter Function to condense multiple horizontal filters into 1 vertical filter

Tags: arrays, excel, syntax, brackets, filterfunction

I am trying to duplicate something I have been able to use in Google Sheets.

Using a the following formula I am able to condense a number of filter functions that normally would present horizontally and present them as a single vertical data set. The example below normally contains about 15 separate filters which are then displayed as one continuous filter.

```
=Filter({'Lookup Chart'!C2:D;'Lookup Chart'!E2:F}, {'Lookup Chart'!C2:C;'Lookup Chart'!E2:E}<>"")
```

In Excel, if I input the following, excel is happy

```
=FILTER(Filter(Lookup_Chart!C2:D100,Lookup_Chart!C2:C100<>"")
```

If I then add curly brackets to add more variables, I get the following error.

[image: Basic Broken Formula Error]

I have tried using named ranges as well. Name ranges work great for the base filter function, but as soon as I add curly brackets excel provides the same error.

Thank you much for you help.

Comment: If you want to add multiple variables, scroll down to the part of this article that says more than one criteria. Excel syntax is kinda weird sometimes. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function

Comment: @Hooded0ne thanks for pointing me in that direction. I think part of the problem is I am not sufficiently knowledgeable to explain the problem. Based on reviewing the link you provided, the =filter I have been using in google sheets is combining multiple ranges, all with the same criteria for said range, into one massive filtered data set.

Comment: Let me try and explain it a different way. I have a number of data sets, each 2 columns wide. I would like to combine all these columns into one single data set that is 2 columns wide, effectively stacking the existing data sets, but only showing rows where this is data. Using the filter function, I can filter for the criteria <b><>""</b>, removing all the blank spaces. The function above was using the filter function to condense all the data an d exclude any rows with blanks, almost like a dynamic range.